# The missing vector derivative operation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, vector-analysis

Generally, the differential operator $d$ takes differential $k$-forms to $(k+1)$-forms.  In $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or more generally on an oriented Riemannian manifold), we can identify vector fields with $1$-forms and $(n-1)$-forms, and functions with $0$-forms and $n$-forms.  If we write $\phi$ for the map between vector fields and 1-forms, and $\psi$ for the map between vector fields and $(n-1)$-forms, then the composite

function $=$ 0-form $\xrightarrow{d}$ 1-form $\xrightarrow{\phi}$ vector field

is the gradient, and the composite

vector field $\xrightarrow{\psi}$ $(n-1)$-form $\xrightarrow{d}$ $n$-form $=$ function

is the divergence.  When $n=3$, we also have the composite

vector field $\xrightarrow{\phi}$ 1-form $\xrightarrow{d}$ 2-form $\xrightarrow{\psi}$ vector field

which is the curl.  And when $n=2$, we have the composite

vector field $\xrightarrow{\phi}$ 1-form $\xrightarrow{d}$ 2-form $=$ function

which is the "scalar curl" that appears in Green's theorem.  Note that it differs from the $n=2$ case of the divergence only in that it involves $\phi$ rather than $\psi$.  When $n=2$ both $\phi$ and $\psi$ relate vector fields to 1-forms, but they do it differently; we have $\phi(\langle F,G\rangle) = F\,dx + G\,dy$, while $\psi(\langle F,G\rangle) = -G\,dx + F\,dy$.

This suggests that there is another way to put these together when $n=2$:

function $=$ 0-form $\xrightarrow{d}$ 1-form $\xrightarrow{\psi}$ vector field

This looks like the $n=2$ case of the gradient, but involves $\psi$ rather than $\phi$.  In coordinates, it takes a function $f$ to the vector field $\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} , -\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\rangle$.

I've never seen this operation before; does it have a name?  It seems potentially interesting, e.g. when we specialize the generalized Stokes' theorem to it we get an FTC for its *flux* line integrals along curves, analogous to the usual FTC for the *flow* line integral of a gradient field.

Comment: This is the Hodge star operator applied to the gradient. In my calculus courses I just call the operation "rotation by 90 degrees".  In ODE courses sometimes this is called a planar Hamiltonian system.  I think that's the bulk of the verbiage surrounding this construction.

Comment: Yes, "Hodge star of the differential" is another way to say it.  What operation are you calling "rotation by 90 degrees"?  I can't think of any sense in which $\langle \partial f/\partial y, -\partial f/\partial x\rangle$ is a "rotation of $f$ by 90 degrees".

Comment: The linear transformation of the plane $(x,y) \longmapsto (y,-x)$ is rotation by 90 degrees, or in the complex plane, multiplication by $i$. That's what I meant.